# Trigger multimple events from one click button - write to database & render an HTML

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax, dropdown

Here is my scenario.

I am building a website where I have created a dependent dropdown menu.
Say select A(first dropdown) then select A2 (second Dropdown) ----> Submit

Then I am writing the values to databse (A-A2). Below is the flow.
Submit button in JS --> Call funciton in views.py --> writing to database.

In JS, I have used 2 event handlers on same **itemForm** object:

```
itemForm.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('submitted')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/create/',
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
            'firstItem': firstitemText.textContent,
            'secondItem': seconditemText.textContent,
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
            alertBox.innerHTML = `<div class="ui positive message">
                                    <div class="header">
                                    Success
                                    </div>
                                    <p>Your order has been placed</p>
                                </div>`
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
            alertBox.innerHTML = `<div class="ui negative message">
                                    <div class="header">
                                    Ops
                                    </div>
                                    <p>Something went wrong</p>
                                </div>`
        }
    })


itemForm.addEventListener('submit', e=>{
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('submitted')
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `orders/${seconditemText.textContent}`,
        data: {
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf[0].value,
            'firstItem': firstitemText.textContent,
            'secondItem': seconditemText.textContent,
        },
        success: function(response){
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
})
```

Now from second event handler, I want to call same html file and render a plot as shown below:

In views.py:

```
def main_view(request):
    qs = FirstItem.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'orders/main.html', {'qs':qs})

#Some other views funtion for writing data to dropdown, which might not be relevant

def create_order(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        secondItem = request.POST.get('firstitem') (first item coming from js file)
        Order.objects.create(firstItem=A, secondItem=A2)


def render_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
    seconditem = kwargs.get('seconditem')
    item_milestone = main_query_script(seconditem) //this is to fetch some data from database
    context_dict.update(item_milestone)
    return render(request, 'main.html', context=context_dict)
```

In orders/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    #some other urls
    path('create/', create_order, name='create-order'),
    path('order/<str:seconditem>', render_function, name='render-function'),
]
```

My questions from above:

- Create_order is going fine from first event handler. But main.html is not getting rendered from second evendhandler
- If I am doing it wrong what am I missing? I want to render the html file and some graphs from the values selected the second dropdown menu coming from second eventhandler url parameter.

Errors I am getting:

```
Internal Server Error: /orders/A2 
... 
... 
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: main.html
```

Note: Please suggest some extra insight as well in similar scenarios if you have. For e.g do's and Don'ts

Comment: You're adding two event handler functions to the form's submission event, which means they will both run essentially in parallel, especially given that both run (asynchronous) ajax requests. In no way will the second one wait for the first to finish here. Also, sending back a rendered view as response to an ajax request only makes sense if you then insert the received view into the page in the success callback, because ajax requests do not make the browser navigate to the result.

Comment: Assuming that you want to 1. process form data 2. generate a view based on that and 3. display it to the user, you need to a) move the second ajax call *into* the first call's success callback, then b) in the second ajax calls' success callback, insert the server reply into the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the information. Can you please elaborate the second part: "b) in the second ajax calls' success callback, insert the server reply into the DOM "

Comment: All you currently have in there is `console.log(response)`. Your backend seems to render `main.html` as response to an `orders/...` request, so you would a) render *only*, say, a <table>...</table> and b) do `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = response;` instead

Comment: I can get the response, but I want to render the data selected to a plot using plotly.js. How to render context values to html? Azax lets use the link to call the function in views, but can it allow to navigate to different html page?

Comment: I want to call a function in views.py from javascript file using ajax and after that trigger a function in views which will render some values in HTML. This is the main requirement.